# Dragging an email with attachment to another mailbox looses attachment

Tags: macos, mail.app

I was dragging an email message in Mail.app and intended to drag it to another folder.  I accidentally went too far and then I was dragging an icon around the Dashboard.  when I went back to Mail.app, the message was still there but missing the attachment.  Where did it go?

It happened to me a second time, but this time the Dashboard wasn't involved.  Is this a bug in Mail.app?  The attachments were photos that were being displayed in-line.

I am using IMAP.  So I can access the photo on my iPhone but it is not accessible on mail.app.  I guess I need to file a RDAR.

Answer (score 1):

The file may be in **/Users/*uname*/Library/Containers/com.apple.mail/Data/Library/Mail Downloads**

(This is where Mail stores *unsaved* attachments)

Comment: The attachments were not in this folder (but there were other previous attachments).